# ¿Cómo ejecutar un comando dentro de un 'container' de Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tengo un contenedor funcionando (Status -> UP) y lo que quiero es poder ejecutar un comando dentro del contenedor docker, si abro la consola y hago un ls por ejemplo, se realiza en mi máquina pero no en el contenedor docker. Y también como se haría con docker-compose.

Comment: Has intentado `docker run -it ID_CONTENEDOR` y dentro de la consola ejecutar el comando?

Comment: Creo que deberias agregar mas informacion, como que contenedor estas usando, o que pretendes hacer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es el comando `exec`:

```
$ docker exec --help
Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container

Options:
  -d, --detach               Detached mode: run command in the background
      --detach-keys string   Override the key sequence for detaching a container
  -e, --env list             Set environment variables
      --help                 Print usage
  -i, --interactive          Keep STDIN open even if not attached
      --privileged           Give extended privileges to the command
  -t, --tty                  Allocate a pseudo-TTY
  -u, --user string          Username or UID (format: <name|uid>[:<group|gid>])
```

Entonces:

> Run a command in a running container

Quiere decir que puedes usar este `exec` para ejecutar un comando en un contenedor en ejecución. Por lo tanto, si quiseras listar los archivos y carpetas:

```
$ docker exec -i nombre-contenedor ls -l
total 56
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jun 20 06:08 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 30  2016 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Aug 10 15:34 dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug  9 19:20 docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 3986 Jul 17 21:55 entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x  40 root root 4096 Aug 10 15:34 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 30  2016 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jun 20 06:08 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Jun 20 06:08 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 30  2016 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 30  2016 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 30  2016 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 162 root root    0 Aug 10 15:34 proc
dr-xr-x---   3 root root 4096 Jul 17 21:55 root
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4096 Aug 10 15:34 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Jun 20 06:08 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 30  2016 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Aug 10 15:34 sys
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root 4096 Aug 10 15:59 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root 4096 Jun 20 06:08 usr
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root 4096 Aug 10 15:34 var
```

El flag `-i` es para ejecutarlo de manera interactiva.

Docker Compose es una herramienta para gestionar múltiples contenedores. Recuerda que los contenedores trabajan con un `Dockerfile` y es en este archivo en donde ejecutas los comandos para el contenedor. Ejemplo de un `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Los comandos los ejecutas con `RUN`.

Comment: Y también podría usarlo con docker-compose exec nombre-contenedor ls -l, no?

Comment: @RodriKing así es

Answer (score 1):

> lo que quiero es poder ejecutar un comando dentro del contenedor docker, si abro la consola y hago un ls por ejemplo, se realiza en mi máquina pero no en el contenedor docker.

Para complementar un poco la información suministrada por @César coloco los siguientes ejemplos:

**1) Ejemplo ls -a**

```
docker exec maps ls /
```

[image: ejemplo_docker_ls]

***Descripción:*** En la imagen anterior se observa como se puede ejecutar un ls -a dentro del contenedor denominado "maps". No sólo se puede ejecutar el comando dentro de docker sino que también se pueden pasar los parámetros asociados al comando tal como funciona de forma nativa. En este caso se pueden observar los directorios ubicados en la raíz del sistema operativo incluidos aquellos ocultos.

**2) Ejemplo mkdir**

```
docker exec maps mkdir /directorio
```

[image: ejemplo_docker_mkdir]

***Descripción:*** En la imagen anterior se puede observar como se crea un directorio que se ubica en la raíz del sistema ejecutado dentro de docker.

**3) Ejemplo touch**

```
docker exec maps touch /archivo
```

[image: ejemplo_docker_touch]

***Descripción:*** En la imagen anterior se muestra como crear un archivo dentro de docker mediante la ejecución del comando touch.

4) Lista de comandos disponibles en docker

```
docker exec maps ls /bin
```

[image: Comandos_disponibles_docker]

***Descripción:*** Para conocer los comandos disponibles del sistema operativo en cuestión (su distribución especifica como Debian por ejemplo) se puede realizar un ls a la carpeta bin ubicada en la raíz del sistema "/bin". Es importante mencionar que no todos los comandos que están presentes de forma nativa en el sistema operativo pueden ejecutarse dentro del contenedor. Un claro ejemplo sería el comando "cd" (cambiar de directorio)

**5) Ejemplo de cd (comando no disponible)**

```
docker exec maps cd /bin
```

[image: cd_no_disponible]

Espero sea de ayuda! Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En caso que quieras utilizar docker-compose, deberías de tener un archivo docker-compose.yml con la configuración de los container a levantar, en ese caso vas a la ruta donde tienes el archivo docker-compose.yml y sigues la siguiente sintaxis: docker-compose exec  , en mi caso tengo un container que le llame **postgres** y quiero ejecutar **sh** por tanto quedaría así: **docker-compose exec postgres sh**, aqui te paso mi docker-compose.yml:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te recomiendo realizar solo una respuesta que ayude a resolver lo que el OP describe en su pregunta, puedes editar tu respuesta también, revisar [answer].

Comment: ok muchas gracias, realmente soy nuevo en el sitio. :)