# Ejecutar un comando en una carpeta dentro de un contenedor con docker exec

Tags: bash, docker, exec

Viendo la información que he encontrado [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94188/c%C3%B3mo-ejecutar-un-comando-dentro-de-un-container-de-docker) y tomándolo como referencia, quisiera poder ejecutar desde el SO Host (linux) un comando dentro de una carpeta específica que se encuentra dentro de un contenedor.

La idea es la siguiente:

Dentro del contenedor web hay una carpeta ngapp; dentro de la misma quiero ejecutar el siguiente comando: `ng build --deleteOutputPath=false --output-path=/home/www/`

```
docker exec -i web cd /home/ngapp ng build --deleteOutputPath=false --output-path=/home/www/
```

Pero no funciona.

**Gracias de antemano. !!** :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta con `docker exec -i web bash -c "etc"`

Por ejemplo:

```
docker exec \
    -i web \
    bash -c "cd /home/ngapp; ng build --deleteOutputPath=false --output-path=/home/www/"
```

Esto es porque `cd` esta contenido en `bash`; es decir, no es un programa que esté en el `$PATH`, sino que es parte del equipamiento que ya incluye el `bash` que todos conocemos y amamos.

### Actualización.

Anduve de curioso revisando `docker exec --help` y encontré este parametro `-w, --workdir <STRING>` el cual indica sobre en qué directorio del contenedor correr el comando o programa.

Entonces, tu caso podría prescindir de `cd` si únicamente le ponemos la ruta absoluta delante del parametro `-w`:

#### Opción 2.1

```
docker exec \
    -i web \
    -w "/home/ngapp" \
    bash -c "ng build --deleteOutputPath=false --output-path=/home/www/"
```

#### Opción 2.2

Lo que no sé, porque nunca lo he usado y mi sentido común y conocimientos no me dan para mas por el momento, es si —para ese comando en específico— puedes prescindir de `bash -c`, es decir, si puedes correr:

```
docker exec \
    -i web \
    -w "/home/ngapp" \
    ng build --deleteOutputPath=false --output-path=/home/www/
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo ahora y te cuento como fue el experimento. Millones de gracias ... !!! @Cuauhtli... !!!

Comment: Me da el siguiente error..

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-w\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: De nada ¡Súper que te haya funcionado!

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado con la primera versión .

```
docker exec \
    -i web \
    bash -c "cd /home/ngapp; ng build --deleteOutputPath=false --output-path=/home/www/"
```

Ha realizado toda la tarea desde Docker !!! Gracias.. !